# Creating a Check Constraint that Relies on the Information in another Table it References

Tags: t-sql, constraints

To explain:

In one table, lets call it `GroupMember`, there is a column called `JoinDate`. `GroupMember`s are allocated to `Group`s which has a `DateFounded`.

```
Group
--------
GroupID identity int (PK)
DateFounded datetime


GroupMember
--------
GroupMemberID identity int (PK)
GroupID int (FK)
JoinDate datetime
```

I want to have a constraint on the `GroupMember` column `JoinDate`, that will prevent it from being entered as before the `DateFounded` for it's `Group`. How should I approach it? Can I use a check constraint? Or do I need a function/trigger?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It can be done but it's a little messy (and does use a trigger, but only to support insertion, not to enforce the actual constraint):

```
create table dbo.Group (
    GroupID int identity not null primary key,
    DateFounded datetime not null,
    constraint UQ_Group_Founded UNIQUE (GroupID,DateFounded)
)
go
create table dbo._GroupMember (
    GroupMemberID int identity not null primary key,
    GroupID int not null references Group (GroupID)
    JoinDate datetime not null,
    _Founded datetime not null,
    constraint FK_GroupMember_Founding FOREIGN KEY (GroupID,_Founded) references Group (GroupID,DateFounded),
    constraint CK_GroupMember_NoTimeTravel CHECK (JoinDate >= _Founded)
)
go
create view dbo.GroupMember
with schemabinding
as
     select GroupMemberID,GroupID,JoinDate
     from dbo.GroupMember
go
create trigger T_GroupMember_I
on dbo.GroupMember
instead of insert
as
    insert into dbo._GroupMember (GroupID,JoinDate,_Founded)
    select i.GroupID,i.JoinDate,g.DateFounded
    from inserted i inner join Group g on i.GroupID = g.GroupID
```

And now you treat the view `GroupMember` as if it was your original `GroupMember` table and ignore the `_GroupMember` table.

It's up to you whether you continue to have the plain foreign key constraint to `Group` as well as the one that includes the `DateFounded` column. And if you want to allow that date to be adjusted in `Group`, you should mark the foreign key as `ON UPDATE CASCADE` and it should automatically adjust the stored value in `_GroupMember` and fail the update if the check constraint is then broken.